# Does Android and Apache MINA work Together?

Tags: android, tcp, tcpclient, apache-mina

I want to create a Mina clients for Android devices, and the Mina server on PC. 
Is that possible ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I dont know if there is a JVM available for Android platform to run Java applications. I roughly remember that there is/was one JVM still under development, optimised for running on the mobile platforms. But if there exists a JVM, then yes you can have a java client (whether or not based on Apache MINA) on the device talking to a Server on your PC. Basically, you need your android device connected to your LAN and then you can communicate with any of the network resources. When you connect to a WiFi network, your device is assigned an IP and once this is done it is as simple and similar to talking between two PCs.

Comment: There are FTP servers available for android devices through which you can connect to your device from your PC and upload/download files to/from your PC. This is an example and you can have your application working in a similar way. But ofcourse you need to have a JVM available on the device to run your java applications.